# Posting task on a particular project via CURL

Tags: php, asana

I seem to have got stuck trying to use the Asana API. I am trying to post a task on a **particular project**.

Here is what I am trying:

```
$api = 'myapikey';
$url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Don't print the result
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // Don't verify SSL connection
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); //         ""           ""
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $api);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
$data = array(
    "data" => array(
        "workspace" => "workspace id",
        "name" => "Task Name",
        "notes" => "notes",
        "assignee" => "assignee id"
    )
);
$data = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);        
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$html = json_decode($html);
var_dump($html);
```

It didn't work, It creates the task on `Undefined Project`. I tried with the following variations:

1. `$url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/projects/4649161839339/tasks';`
2. `$url = 'https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/projects/4649161839339';`

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add projects to tasks at creation time by specifying a `projects` field, which consists of an array of project IDs to add the task to, i.e.: `"projects" => [4649161839339],`. This should be covered in the developer documentation.

For PHP

```
$data = array(
    "data" => array(
        "workspace" => "workspace id",
        "projects" => array('project_id'),
        "name" => "Task Name",
        "notes" => "notes",
        "assignee" => "assignee id"
    )
);
```

Once the task is created, you can use the `/tasks/ID/addProject` and `/tasks/ID/removeProject` endpoints to add and remove projects.

Comment: Well, I didn't find it. I will give this a try.

Comment: You should consider adding this to the documentation.